# How can i get the document path in a JSON File of a directory tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My problem is the easy searching / path finding in a JSON file.

The project is a web application. Someone can enter a "documentnumber" (something like 48555 001 00-8.pdf) in a search field and when this person hits Enter a link to this document appears.

My searching for the document path is too slow, complicated, bad. Just bad.
My idea was to get all the directories as an array, then search through this for the "customer 555" and so on, until I reach the correct document. But here is the problem: it is really slow and... what can I do if there is one more directory / folder then I think. And what is, if the document is in another folder as I expect because of .. yeah .. humans. So, not the best idea I guess.

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
      {"type":"directory","name":"documents/","contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"customer 555","contents":[
          {"type":"directory","name":"product 1","contents":[
            {"type":"directory","name":"product 1.2","contents":[
              {"type":"directory","name":"changes","contents":[
                {"type":"file","name":"changes.zip"}
              ]},
              {"type":"directory","name":"document 8","contents":[
                {"type":"file","name":"48555 001 00-8.pdf"},
              ]},
    ....
```

In the end I would like to have a path like this:

```
localhost/documents/customer 555/product 1/product 1.2/document 8/48555 001 00-8.pdf
```

That's the path to this file on my Apache server.

Is there a solution to get the path directly? Let's say, I'm searching for "48555 001 00-8.pdf" and then go up (the directories) to the top directory "documents/"? Or is there a lib or method that can give me the location in the tree?

I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: You can flatten the array first then search for the match

Comment: Do you have control over this JSON format? Because ... damn.

Comment: I got it by tipping "tree -J path/to/folder/ > file.json" into the terminal .. if there is another way .. please tell me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplest terms you need to have a way to search for filenames and have access to their path at the same time.

So you can either do it yourself by extracting the following from the output you posted (recurse through the JSON heirarchy):

```
var files = [
    {
        "name": "48555 001 00-8.pdf",
        "path": "documents/customer 555/product 1/product 1.2/document 8/48555 001 00-8.pdf"
    }, {
        "name": "changes.zip",
        "path": "documents/customer 555/product 1/product 1.2/changes/changes.zip"
    }
]
```

Or use your server-side technology to search for files, i.e. in node you could use the package: [find](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find):

```
var find = require('find');

// Filter by regular expression.

find.file(/48555 001 00-8\.pdf/, __dirname, function(files) {
  console.log(files.length);
})
```

Don't forget to sanitize the user input to escape regexp special characters

Comment: The find package does exactly what i want without the need of a json file. Thank you.